# Prepend text into each tag with specific ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tags-input

I have a tag system implemented into my website for three different categories. I set it up for a twitter account so I have "Keywords", "Mentions" and "Hashtags".  What I need is that when a user inserts a tag in the `text input` for **Mentions** for it to `prepend` a "@" symbol before the text entered.  The same goes for **Hashtags** except for the "#" symbol.  I have put together a demo of what I have so far.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanverdel/WUFdr/)

```
<div id="wrapper">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <td id="keyword-filter">
            <h5>Keywords</h5>
            <input type="text"  id="keywordInput">
            <br>
            Include:
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="keywordInclude" checked="true">Any
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="keywordInclude">All
            <b>Keywords</b>
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <td id="mention-filter">
            <h5>Mentions</h5>
            <input type="text"  id="mentionInput">
            <br>
            Include:
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="mentionInclude" checked="true">Any
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="mentionInclude">All
            <b>Mentions</b>             
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <td id="tag-filter">
            <h5>Hashtags</h5>
            <input type="text"  id="hashtagInput">  
            <br>
            Include:
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="tagsInclude" checked="true">Any
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="tagsInclude">All
            <b>Hashtags</b>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation and source code of the tagsInput plugin you can use the `onAddTag` callback to fire whenever a tag is added. You can grab the tag element which is just created in the DOM and prepend the text with a @.
See the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WUFdr/3/) for a working example. You also need to check if the user didn't enter a @ already.

```
$('#mentionInput').tagsInput({
    'defaultText':'add name',
    'onAddTag':function(tag) {
        var span = $('#mentionInput_tagsinput .tag span').last();
        if (span.text().substring(0, 1) != '@') {
            span.text('@' + span.text());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks you @Bram, I must have skipped over the `onAddTag` function callback in their documentation.  I appreciate your help.  I'm glad you included the if statement regarding if the user entered that symbol already, otherwise it would keep adding to all the tags. Thanks again!